# Create 5-minute interval between two timestamp

Tags: python, hive, pyspark

I have a bunch of data point for each there are two columns: `start_dt` and `end_dt`. I am wondering how can I split the time gap between start_dt and end_dt into 5 minutes interval?

For instance,

**id+++++++start_tm ++++++++++++++ end_dt**

1+++++++2019-01-01 10:00 +++++++ 2019-01-01 11:00

=====================================================

What I am looking for is:

**id+++++++start_tm ++++++++++++++ end_dt**

1+++++++2019-01-01 10:00 +++++++ 2019-01-01 10:05

1+++++++2019-01-01 10:05 +++++++ 2019-01-01 10:10

1+++++++2019-01-01 10:10 +++++++ 2019-01-01 10:15

1+++++++2019-01-01 10:15 +++++++ 2019-01-01 10:20

==================================================

and so fort

is there any function out of the box to do so?

If not, any help to create this function is wonderful

Comment: I don't understand the problem, maybe because I don't know hive or pyspark.  Are the strings you are showing here just representational, or are you asking about just some string and date manipulations?  Is this just about taking input like you show below "For instance" and turning it into output like what you show below "What I am looking for is"?  You just want to extract the dates from a string, and produce new strings?

Comment: Steve, start_tm is not string but timestamp. These rows are representational- only example. So, for any start_dt value, I should be able to add 5 minute intervals to it until it reaches end_dt. If not clear, let me provide more detail.

Comment: so you have start_dt and end_dt as python datetime objects?  and you just want to create all the datetime objects for the the 5 minute intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two Python datetime objects representing a timespan, and you just want to break that timespan up into 5 minute intervals represented by datetime objects, you could just do this:

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 0)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 11, 0)
delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
times = []
while d1 < d2:
    times.append(d1)
    d1 += delta
times.append(d2)

for i in range(len(times) - 1):
    print("{} - {}".format(times[i], times[i+1]))
```

Output:

```
2019-01-01 10:00:00 - 2019-01-01 10:05:00
2019-01-01 10:05:00 - 2019-01-01 10:10:00
2019-01-01 10:10:00 - 2019-01-01 10:15:00
2019-01-01 10:15:00 - 2019-01-01 10:20:00
2019-01-01 10:20:00 - 2019-01-01 10:25:00
2019-01-01 10:25:00 - 2019-01-01 10:30:00
2019-01-01 10:30:00 - 2019-01-01 10:35:00
2019-01-01 10:35:00 - 2019-01-01 10:40:00
2019-01-01 10:40:00 - 2019-01-01 10:45:00
2019-01-01 10:45:00 - 2019-01-01 10:50:00
2019-01-01 10:50:00 - 2019-01-01 10:55:00
2019-01-01 10:55:00 - 2019-01-01 11:00:00
```

This should handle a period that isn't an even multiple of the delta, giving you a shorter interval at the end.

Comment: I think he's looking for start and end columns.  And maybe add "import datetime" :)

Comment: ah, yes on both counts. - Thanks @AlexK!

Comment: @Steve, if you don't mind, can you pls upvote my question? Not sure why it is being downvotted!

Comment: Hi @Espanta.  Done!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know pyspark, but if you are using pandas this works. (and pyspark may be similar):

1:create data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1, 2],
    'start_tm': pd.date_range('2019-01-01 00:00', periods=2, freq='D'),
    'end_dt': pd.date_range('2019-01-01 00:30', periods=2, freq='D')})
# pandas dataframe is similar to the data in pyspark
```

output

```
id  start_tm    end_dt
1   2019-01-01  2019-01-01 00:30:00
2   2019-01-02  2019-01-02 00:30:00
```

2: split columns

```
period = np.timedelta64(5, 'm') # 5 minutes
idx = (data['end_dt'] - data['start_tm']) > period
while idx.any():
    new_data = data[idx].copy()
    new_data['start_tm'] = new_data['start_tm'] + period
    data.loc[idx, 'end_dt'] = (data[idx]['start_tm'] + period).values
    data = pd.concat([data, new_data], axis=0)
    idx = (data['end_dt'] - data['start_tm']) > period
```

output

```
id  start_tm    end_dt
1   2019-01-01 00:00:00     2019-01-01 00:05:00
2   2019-01-02 00:00:00     2019-01-02 00:05:00
1   2019-01-01 00:05:00     2019-01-01 00:10:00
2   2019-01-02 00:05:00     2019-01-02 00:10:00
1   2019-01-01 00:10:00     2019-01-01 00:15:00
2   2019-01-02 00:10:00     2019-01-02 00:15:00
1   2019-01-01 00:15:00     2019-01-01 00:20:00
2   2019-01-02 00:15:00     2019-01-02 00:20:00
1   2019-01-01 00:20:00     2019-01-01 00:25:00
2   2019-01-02 00:20:00     2019-01-02 00:25:00
1   2019-01-01 00:25:00     2019-01-01 00:30:00
2   2019-01-02 00:25:00     2019-01-02 00:30:00
```

Comment: and it's quite easy to convert between pandas `dataframe` and pyspark `dataframe`, you can search for some other answers for doing this.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers of you and Steve. Since Steve has responded first, I accepted his. Thanks Woods!